# How to print score of stone, paper and scissiors in python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

currently I am making a simple game of stone, paper and scissors where u take input from user and see through random module the input of computer. The user gets 10 chances and whoever has the most wins, wins the game. Here is my code

```
import random

print("Hi lets play stone, paper and scissors")
inp = input("what is your input, stone, paper or scissors")

lst = ["Stone", "paper", "Scissors"]
rand = random.choice(lst)

n = 1
player = 0
comp  = 0

while n<=9:
    n = n+1
    if inp == "Stone" or "sto" or "Sto" and rand == "Scissors":
        comp = comp +1
        print(comp)    
    else:
        print("Unexpected error")
```

Here, first I am importing random module then asking the user for his/her input. Then I am making a list and choosing the computer's input. I am then initializing the guess as n and the value is 0, comp is the computer score which is 0 and player is player score which is also 0. Then in a while loop I am making n's value n+1, the problem is that when I am doing comp = n+1 then its printing from 1 to 9 not making the score 1. I don't understand why this is happening. Pls help.

edit --->

```
import random

print("Hi lets play stone, paper and scissors")

lst = ["Stone", "paper", "Scissors"]
rand = random.choice(lst)

n = 1


while n<=9:
    player = 0
    comp  = 1
    inp = input("what is your input, stone, paper or scissors")
    n = n+1
    if inp == "Stone" and rand == "Scissors":
        comp = comp +1
        print(comp)    
    else:
        print("Unexpected error")
```

Comment: That is probably because you're using the first round's inputs - both the user's and the computer's - for every round. You're not asking for new input in the loop nor are you choosing the computer's value again.

Comment: your loop only uses the first input and random value. it seemingly goes through every round in the game but there aren't actually rounds - it just does the same thing again and again because the values don't change

Comment: also, your condition won't work - you can't do `var == x or y or z` when seeing if a value is one of three, you could use `var in [x, y, z]` or in your case `inp in ["Stone", "sto", "Sto"]`

Comment: yes I got it, I put all the inputs under the while loop but the value of computer is not increasing, it is remaing 1

Comment: can you show what you've done?

Comment: import random

print("Hi lets play stone, paper and scissors")

lst = ["Stone", "paper", "Scissors"]
rand = random.choice(lst)

n = 1


while n<=9:
    player = 0
    comp  = 1
    inp = input("what is your input, stone, paper or scissors")
    n = n+1
    if inp == "Stone" and rand == "Scissors":
        comp = comp +1
        print(comp)    
    else:
        print("Unexpected error")

Comment: Please put it as an edit to the post, not in a comment. Comments don't preserve indentation

Comment: yes, done please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243323/discussion-between-strangesorcerer-and-arnav-tripathi).